# python3 python-escpos: product id / PID for EPSON TM-M30 needed

Tags: python-3.x, printing, epson, escpos

Since some years I am running and maintaining an online P.O.S. system, where peripheral hardware  and print system is managed by a RasPi with pure debian & python3.

My costumer bought a new receipt printer, which is an EPSON TM-M30.
Currently he's using a TM-T88IV for that.

The python-escpos printer code snippet currently is

```
p = printer.Usb(0x04b8, 0x0202, 0)
```

Do I need anything to change for the new printer (googeling since hours I cannot find a PID for this new printer)

I know that with the new printer ethernet an WiFi is also available and I can use

```
p = printer.Network("192.168.178.77", 0) // port might differ
```

for that, but stiil I want to be able to use it with USB if needed.

**Notice:** I found the same PID here 
http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids
for the TM-T70 and I guess that the PID 0x0202 is valid for more than one thermal printer, but need to be sure.

Thanks for any helpful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface board of the EPSON printer is modularized and commonly used by many printers.
[Interface Board](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=genre&pcat=53)
[UB-U](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=prod&pcat=53&pid=3598)

The PID is for that interface board and is the same for any printer that uses it.

For example, for Japanese materials, the PID is the same for TM-m30 and TM-T88VI.
[TM-m30](https://www2.epson.jp/support/manual/TM-m30_trg_ja_revF.pdf) page 86
[TM-T88VI](https://partner.epson.jp/support/details/contents033/pdf/TM-T88VI_trg_ja_revB.pdf) page 118

Therefore, VID 0x04B8 and PID 0x0202 can be considered as IDs of USB interface boards of EPSON printers.

If you can get the Manufacturer and Product String Descriptors written in the document, you will be able to determine the printer model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Following the links you provided I found a tech reference for TM-M30, https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/download.php?fid=8801#page97 shows the interface specs, and - as you mentioned - the PID is the same: 0202. So thanks again, 1+

Comment: The UB-U board is not used in the TM-m30.  The modularized interface boards are only used for some printer (T88, L500 etc.).  TM-m30 has an internal board an thus a different USB product ID.  See my answer below.

Comment: It depends on the mode setting of the device. And you should be able to change it with configuration tool or manual. Of course, after changing modes, you need to install the appropriate device driver.

Answer (score 0):

The EPSON TM-m30 has a USB vendor ID of 04b8 and a USB product ID of 0e20.

lsusb on my RHEL 8 shows the printer as Seiko EPSON, 04b8:0e20.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your contribution. Will check this out later and I'll be back to you.

Comment: It will depend on the interface board model you are using. If the interface board changes, it may be another PID.

Comment: you cannot change the interface board in the TM-m30.

Comment: I overlooked it. It depends on the mode of the device.
0x0202 in serial port emulation mode and 0x0E20 in USBPrint device mode. Please read the material carefully.

Comment: The later is the default mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lsusb` to find the vendor id and product id.
The following script will help you with that (see its readme for more details) and will also give you the endpoint ids: https://gist.github.com/elsholz/44643ede809a6c4a3875beaae26bff2f